# Having trouble Parsin a JSON Array in Android Studio

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

I tough i knew the way to parse a JSON but when I try to access to the key where the value i want is Android Studio gives me the following message:

[image: org.JSON.JSONEXCEPTION: no value for large]

As you can see it says that there is no value for the key "large" but clearly it is, anyway, this is my json parse method

```
 public static List<News> parseJSONtoNews(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {
    List<News> newsList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        News news = new News();
        JSONObject jsonObjectNews = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        JSONArray jsonArrayCategories = jsonObjectNews.getJSONArray(JSONKeys.KEY_CATEGORIES);


        int category = getCatgories(jsonArrayCategories);
        news.setCategories(category);

        news.setiD(jsonObjectNews.getInt("id"));

        JSONObject jsonObjectTitle = jsonObjectNews.getJSONObject("title");
        news.setTitle(jsonObjectTitle.getString("rendered"));

        JSONObject jsonObjectContent = jsonObjectNews.getJSONObject("content");
        news.setContent(jsonObjectContent.getString("rendered"));

        JSONObject jsonObjectImage = jsonObjectNews.getJSONObject("better_featured_image");
        JSONObject jsonObjectMediaDetails = jsonObjectImage.getJSONObject("media_details");
        JSONObject jsonObjectSizes = jsonObjectMediaDetails.getJSONObject("sizes");
        JSONObject jsonObjectMediumLarge = jsonObjectSizes.getJSONObject("large");
        news.setImageURL(jsonObjectMediumLarge.getString("source_url"));
        newsList.add(news);
    }



    return newsList;
}

public static int getCatgories(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException{
    int categories = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
        categories = jsonArray.getInt(i);
    }

    return categories;
}
```

This is the JSON I want to Parse

```
[
  {
    "id": 742,
        "title": {
      "rendered": “title”
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": “content”
    },
    "categories": [
      4
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "better_featured_image": {
        "file": "2016/05/20160520_191324.jpg",
        "sizes": {
          "thumbnail": {
            "file": "20160520_191324-150x150.jpg",
            "source_url": "http://www.aarc.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/20160520_191324-150x150.jpg"
          },
          "medium": {
            "file": "20160520_191324-300x169.jpg",
            "source_url": "http://www.aarc.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/20160520_191324-300x169.jpg"
          },
          "medium_large": {
            "file": "20160520_191324-768x432.jpg",
            "source_url": "http://www.aarc.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/20160520_191324-768x432.jpg"
          },
          "large": {
            "file": "20160520_191324-1024x576.jpg",
            "source_url": "http://www.aarc.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/20160520_191324-1024x576.jpg"
          }
        },
      "post": 742,
      "source_url": "http://www.aarc.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/20160520_191324.jpg"
    },
 },
{
    "id": 745,
        "title": {
      "rendered": “title”
    },
    "content": {
      "rendered": “content”
    },
    "categories": [
      4
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "better_featured_image": {
        "file": "2016/05/20160520_191324.jpg",
        "sizes": {
          "thumbnail": {
            "file": "20160520_191324-150x150.jpg",
            "source_url": "http://www.aarc.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/20160520_191324-150x150.jpg"
          },
          "medium": {
            "file": "20160520_191324-300x169.jpg",
            "source_url": "http://www.aarc.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/20160520_191324-300x169.jpg"
          },
          "medium_large": {
            "file": "20160520_191324-768x432.jpg",
            "source_url": "http://www.aarc.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/20160520_191324-768x432.jpg"
          },
          "large": {
            "file": "20160520_191324-1024x576.jpg",
            "source_url": "http://www.aarc.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/20160520_191324-1024x576.jpg"
          }
        },
      "post": 742,
      "source_url": "http://www.aarc.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/20160520_191324.jpg"
    },
   }
]
```

As you can see there exist the key "large" but i cant access to it, it works with the "thumbnail" key, so I dont know how to hanlde this, i hope you guys could help me! 
Thanks

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android
use Jackson to parse Json instead of manually parsing

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me:

```
JSONObject jsonObjectImage = jsonObjectNews.getJSONObject("better_featured_media");
JSONObject jsonObjectMediaDetails = jsonObjectImage.getJSONObject("media_details");
```

`jsonObjectMediaDetails` shouldn't exist. I don't see `media_details` anywhere in the JSON. I also don't see `better_featured_media`. I think it should be `better_featured_image`.

Try:

```
JSONObject jsonObjectImage = jsonObjectNews.getJSONObject("better_featured_image");
JSONObject jsonObjectSizes = jsonObjectImage.getJSONObject("sizes");
```

Comment: I am sorry but i have all of those keys in a class called JSONKEYS, I wrote it wrong but in my code it says ""better_featured_image", as I told you i can access to the htumbnail key but i cant to the large one, (which is the one that i want) thank you for reply, i appreciate it

Comment: @miguelacio it still looks to me that you are making one extra call you don't need: the `getJsonObject("media_details")`. that key doesn't exist in the JSON you posted. Try adding a breakpoint in that function, and stepping through each statement and checking the value at each step.

Comment: @miguelacio I think Kevin is right, I've also observed the code and 'media_details' key doesn't exist. remove that one and try without it.

Comment: Miguel please do try this. It has to be the correct answer